# How is asynchronous reset physically implemented in a flip-flop?

Tags: flipflop, reset, metastability

In Cliff Cumming's excellent [paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf) on asynchronous vs synchronous resets, the following paragraph about the risk of metastability appears on page 19:

> Attention must be paid to the release of the
>   reset so as to prevent the chip from going into a metastable unknown state when reset is released.
>   When a synchronous reset is being used, then both the leading and trailing edges of the reset
>   must be away from the active edge of the clock.

The paper in particular notes that metastability is *not* a risk when *asserting* reset on a flip-flop with asynchronous reset, and explains why on page 23:

> There is no reset metastability issue when reset is asserted because the reset signal bypasses the
>   clock signal in a flip-flop circuit to cleanly force the output low

How can a asynchronous reset in a flip-flop be implemented such that asserting the reset carries no risk of metastability on the output?

Comment: Actually, I suspect that if you give a short enough reset pulse to an asynchronous reset, you could have metastability issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous reset is level-sensitive so the timing relative to the clock edge is of no importance.

Think of the output cross-coupled gates of a master-slave flip-flop and add inputs to the gates to force the outputs to a given state. For example (from [this](https://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/hades/webdemos/16-flipflops/40-jkff/jkff.html) website):

[image]

So long as the /RESET input is low, the /Q output must be high. In reality it has to be a bit more complex than this because you don't want glitching on the Q output. Here is the gate-level representation of a real D-FF ([74LS74](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls119/sdls119.pdf)):

[image]